# Same error in my console.log to in whatever repo I oepn (companion-bubble.js:1452:20487)

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

I keep receiving the same error in my console in whatever repo I open. I've tried looking up the issue but cant seem to find it anywhere.

Does anyone know why it occurs?

[companion-bubble error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2wTN.png)

Comment: hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, It is highly recommended **to write** the code and the error so we can be able to identify your issue. Also, posting images instead of codes can not help others to share the same issues. In this context, I invite you to take a look at the [Stackoverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you can have an idea about how to write a correct question. Good luck!

Comment: This may be a Chrome extension. Run a repo in incognito mode to see if it still occurs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For me that was Loom plugin in case someone else landed here

Comment: That was the Loom chrome extension for me too. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I just figured out a way to clear this error while developing on Chrome browser.

Open you chrome browser and navigate to [Manage Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc2nE.png).
Once you see the dashboard of extensions go through and manually toggle them all off, then smash a refresh and toggle them back on. Problem solved !

Comment: This is not a solution. There are some extensions that are not supposed to be toggled off. I believe the best solution is to find what's exactly the extension that is causing this.

Comment: Or a simple solution is desable Bumble.io extension from you extensions in Chrome

Comment: For me it was loom video recorder extension